# How to carry Last 24 hours value in time filter from one dashboard to another dashboard in Splunk

Tags: time, splunk

How to carry Last 24 hours value in time filter from one dashboard to another dashboard in Splunk

carrying Last 24 hours value in time filter from one dashboard to another dashboard in Splunk

Carry the time field value from one dashboard to another dashboard

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With Splunk Studio Dashboards you can do this with the interactions

You can do this on any of the visualizations, Icons or Shapes.

Settings are:

On Click: Link to Dashboard

Select an App: the app the dashboard you want is in
Select a Dashboard: the dashboard to link to

Then under Set Tokens, add 2 tokens

```
Token Name           |   Token Value
global_time.latest   |  $global_time.latest$
global_time.earliest |  $global_time.earliest$
```

To Read more on this see the Splunk Studio Dashboard documentation
https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.2.0/DashStudio/linkURL